# How to get access token to team's Bot activity handlers

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

When we have a dialog we

```
     private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
    if (tokenResponse != null)
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to view your token?") }, cancellationToken);
    }

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

how to get the token to the teams bot activity handler , just like the
**var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result**

```
      protected override async Task OnTeamsChannelRenamedAsync(ChannelInfo channelInfo, TeamInfo teamInfo, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 
        var heroCard = new HeroCard(text: $"{channelInfo.Name} is the new Channel name");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(heroCard.ToAttachment()), cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the token to the teams bot activity handler , just like the
> var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result

You don't. Once you obtain the access token, you store it into a variable you can access, such as in your root dialog context's *state*.

Check out documentation on DialogContext, and its State property for managing a Dialog's memory and memory scopes, which is designed specifically for cases like yours where you need to access a token across turns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.state?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#microsoft-bot-builder-dialogs-dialogcontext-state

Also, if you don't have a specific reason to not be using Bot Framework Composer, I highly suggest you check out the Composer instead of trying to handle Auth and everything on your own. Composer comes with all of these dialogs including Auth pre-built, and any custom dialogs or function you want that you cannot achieve within the Composer can be added to the bot can be achieved through Middleware / Custom actions. I say this because if you want to store dialog states consistently you would also need to store the dialog state in some sort of database so you can persist tokens; Composer already handles all of this for you.

Comment: John Kim, thanks for the response. I want to get the access token when the **OnTeamsChannelRenamedAsync**  is triggered is there any code sample I can refer to. 
with respect to  Bot Framework Composer as well can have triggers onTeamsChannelRenamed or any other event handlers

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/14ed6ea596aa84d2b561d00f58f828ae8cc1a89a/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L57
Hope it's helpful.

Comment: If I am not wrong it works only when there is like a question asked by a user to the bot, it is not even hitting when I am debugging that sample. Do we have any bot composer example to trigger when teams activity handler is triggered

Comment: @umgolla 
First create your Auth Dialog class. Again, Composer's pre-built code is helpful here-https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive/Input/OAuthInput.cs

Then you can call your Auth dialog in whichever teams activity handler you want, such as TeamsActivityHandler.OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync.

Comment: @JohnKim, cant we get access token , if we have mentioned it group chat / teams scope only in the manifest

Comment: This sample utilizes an app setting UseSingleSignOn to add TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware. Refer to Teams SSO for AAD and SSO OAuth configuration information.

IMPORTANT: Teams SSO only works in 1-1 chats, and not group contexts.

Comment: @umgolla Hmm, you are correct. Teams SSO is only supported in 1-1 chats, not group context. This is because in a group context you would have to create and manage conversation threads, validate user sign ins for each user (make sure someone else doesn't sign in on a prompt meant to be for a different user), as well as maintain a dictionary of tokens for different users. Your use case is far more complicated than just "obtaining an access token", and far outside the scope that could be provided in a single SO answer.

Comment: @JohnKim, basically i need to make an api call to our api's when TeamsChannel is renamed, is there any better way to achieve it, when we tested it with a dialog we got the accesstoken from `var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result` , but in our case we don't have any dialog at the moment

Comment: I not sure if we could use a Bot Composer on Teams channel is Renamed

Comment: @umgolla You can modify bot composer's code via middleware, and add OnTeamsChannelRenamedAsync to the middleware code to do what you want. Perhaps try downloading the Enterprise Assistant template through the composer and then check out how to implement middleware.